# Missing features on SonarQube interface

Tags: installation, sonarqube

I have installed SonarQube 4.3.1 and have access to results from the sample project.  However, I do not have the full compliment of menus.  On the top bar, I have only a login option.  There is no admin or setting menu.  The left hand column has only hotspots, issues and time machine.  This seems pretty basic but I simply can't figure it out.  I am running this on Windows 7.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please attach a screenshot ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have access to admin or settings menu only when you are logged in with the required privileges.

If you've just installed SonarQube, log in with admin/admin account and you'll get what you want.